# Configure AAM SP2010 Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping

I am attempting to push my SP site out to the internet, so my agency users can access the site from the outside network if need be.  I followed the directions shown at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/configure-an-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx  I extended the SP Web Application to Internet zone using www.sharepoint.abc.123.gov with port 22000.  I setup the port fowarding in the firewall.  All appears to be fine...I can access the SP site internally going to www.sharepoint.abc.123.gov:22000.  But, when I try it from outside the network, it fails and says website not found.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not put an Internet website on port 22000. Use standard port 80 instead, and configure a Host Header in IIS.
Then why can't you access it from outside? Possible answers are:

- The external DNS is not working correctly. Try "ping www.sharepoint.abc.123.gov" to see if you get something.
- A router/proxy/firewall somewhere is not configured correctly. Check that the route from "Internet" to your WFE server is working.